# Python subprocess doesn't run the number of times indicates

Tags: python, subprocess

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import sys
import subprocess
procs=[]
for i in range(9):
    proc=subprocess.Popen(['python3.4','test.py'])
    procs.append(proc)

for proc in procs:
    proc.wait()
```

Sometimes it runs the code 9 times other times it may only run the code 7 times, maybe 8, maybe 6...you know one time to the next how many copies of the program to expect it to run.  It doesn't always run the associated program the same number of times everytime.  How do I correct this so it always runs as many times as desired?

Comment: How do you tell the times? by some dump from test.py? It seems that the code is too simple to be not working?